# getting multiple photos from Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm now playing with Facebook's Graph API and I'm trying to copy Facebook's posts from a page that I'm administrating to another place.

So far I managed to succesfully get `message` and `full_picture`, the problem begins with posts that have several pictures in as if I never get more than one picture from a post.

[Graph API reference for posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/post) tells only about returning one link for one picture or full_picture and I didn't find any mentions about getting the biggest number of pictures possible.

Is there any way to get all pictures from posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them via the attachments, at least for posts I have made

```
$ okurl https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/10153937378849343_10156680000194343/attachments
{
  "data": [
    {
      "subattachments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "media": {
              "image": {
                "height": 540,
                "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p180x540/xxx_n.jpg",
                "width": 720
              }
            },
            "target": {
              "id": "10156680000094343",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxx"
            },
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxx"
          },
          {
            "media": {
              "image": {
                "height": 540,
                "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p180x540/38918411_10156680000119343_5451882299853373440_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=ac71357254bb90e14e4a658531ff370b&oe=5C08C9C2",
                "width": 720
              }
            },
            "target": {
              "id": "10156680000109343",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxx"
            },
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=xxx"
          }
        ]
      },
      "target": {
        "id": "10156680000194343",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/542634342/posts/10156680000194343/"
      },
      "title": "Photos from My post",
      "type": "album",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/542634342/posts/10156680000194343/"
    }
  ]
}
```